# How do I keep my laptop on after closing it and then unplugging it?

Tags: laptop, power, lid, windows-11

Until the Windows 11 update, I had my power options set up so that my laptop would stay on when the lid was closed while it was plugged in. I could then unplug it and it would remain on, which I used to my advantage when I needed to transport it. However, the laptop now turns off as soon as I unplug it even if the lid was closed before unplugging. How do I restore the old behavior?

Comment: I would start by reinstalling the power driver, then set all power settings to default, restart, set up power settings again and test. I am using Windows 11 here by the way.

Comment: Windows 11 isn't an update, it's a beta. Either report it via your insider login or uninstall the beta if you don't want bugs